# Find the difference between two DFs based on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have these two DFs and I want to see the difference between the two DF but only if they're different on the brand, style and rating column.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],
    'style': ['cup',  'cup', 'pack', 'pack'],
    'rating': [4, 3.5, 15, 5],
    'letter': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],
    'style': ['cup',  'cup', 'cup', 'pack'],
    'rating': [4, 3.5, 15, 3],
    'letter': ['C', 'B', 'C', 'D']
})
```

```
df1:      brand style  rating letter
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0      A
1  Indomie   cup     3.5      B
2  Indomie  pack    15.0      C
3  Indomie  pack     5.0      D 

df2:      brand style  rating letter
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0      C
1  Indomie   cup     3.5      B
2  Indomie   cup    15.0      C
3  Indomie  pack     3.0      D
```

I've been able to get the ones that are the same but not the difference. This should be the output:

```
     brand style  rating letter
0  Indomie   cup      15      C
1  Indomie  pack       3      D
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the negation of `isin` together with `all` on axis. This selects the rows in `df2` that are not in `df1`.

```
cols = ['brand','style','rating']
out = df2[~df1[cols].isin(df2[cols]).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
     brand style  rating letter
2  Indomie   cup    15.0      C
3  Indomie  pack     3.0      D
```

That said, it's not clear which one you want to select when it comes to difference, since when you have 2 DataFrames with intersection, there are 3 different parts: (i) exclusively `df1`, (ii) exclusively `df2` and (iii) intersection. You want either (i) or (ii), but it's unclear which one without more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm interested in the differences between the two so (iii) intersection. Preferably I would like to a column that had which df it came from.

Comment: @5sWithCrackScreen intersection would the rows that are the same; you can get them with `df1[df1[cols].isin(df2[cols]).all(axis=1)]` or `df2[df2[cols].isin(df1[cols]).all(axis=1)]`.